# how do i make image show up on screen when touched on screen?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am making a game with corona sdk and I want that when someone touches and slide  the screen a wood plank(image) is made till the point it is slided to(when he lets go off the screen)

please help

Comment: StackOverflow is a place where you get answers to questions about an actual problem you have faced. It is expected that you include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this question [In Corona SDK, how do I limit the number of lines drawn to one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488323/in-corona-sdk-how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-lines-drawn-to-one)

it is almost what you want, but instead of line you need to draw image of wood.

Comment: ah thanks, now i have one more question. I have image of wood. how do i replace it with lines? I want it to act the same way the lines are acting that is when screen touched the line is formed and when you move, it stretches till you stop touching the screen

Comment: help would be appreciated as I am still learning lua and still have a lot to learn and I am trying to make a game while learning. Thank you :)